# Kruskal's MST Algorithm non-deterministic?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, greedy, kruskals-algorithm

The following is pseudo code for Kruskal's Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm from our CS algorithms lecturer. I wanted to know if the MST algorithm is non-deterministic. Given two edges with the same weight, how would the algorithm decide between them if neither edge formed a cycle when adding to T. Surely if it was random then one could not determine the result of what exact edges are added to T?

```
    Given an undirected connected graph G=(V,E)    
    T=Ø //Empty set, i.e. empty
    E'=E
    while E'≠Ø do
    begin
        pick an edge e in E' with minumum weight
        if adding e to T does not form a cycle then
            T = T∪{e} //Set union, add e to T
        E' = E'\{e} //Set difference, remove e from E'
    end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given two edges with the same weight, how would the algorithm decide
>   between them if neither edge formed a cycle when adding to T. Surely
>   if it was random then one could not determine the result of what exact
>   edges are added to T?

This is upto the implementation.

Kruskal's algorithm finds one of the many possible MSTs of a connected weighted graph (which is not a tree). This is because at each iteration you have multiple choices (of choosing an edge from within edges with the same weight). This is the non-deterministic bit. Of course, when you will implement the algorithm you will make a choice (i.e. impose an order) however a different implementation can very well impose a different order. Thus, you will have two implementations of the algorithm, solving the same problem, correctly but *possibly* with different end results.

Answer (score 3):

Kruskal's algorithm is deterministic if you pick a deterministic choice function for the cases where you have a choice, otherwise it's non-deterministic. If you choose randomly, you can't tell which edges end up in the MST if there are several possibilities.